# Community Metapuzzle - The Broken Time Machine

Tags: wordplay, metapuzzles

<sup>(This is the community metapuzzle, discussed in [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/community-metapuzzle) meta thread. It requires answers from nine other puzzles linked below.)</sup>

You find a mysterious device sitting on the ground. It's labelled in a language you don't recognize and doesn't seem to be like anything you've ever seen before. Picking it up, you notice no form of input or output except the button that was face down... which you now seem to have released by lifting it off the ground. The device starts to make a whirring noise. As it vibrates, you suddenly find yourself transported to all sorts of locations, time periods, and situations with seemingly nothing in common...

- [Search the Pantomime 4 Clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45882/search-the-pantomime-4-clues)
- ["The Unfinished ________ Waltz"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45889/the-unfinished-waltz)
- [The Temple of Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45897/the-temple-of-puzzling)
- [The answer is less complex than the riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45904/the-answer-is-less-complex-than-the-riddle)
- [A Puzzle Like Deja Vu All Over Again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45906/a-puzzle-like-deja-vu-all-over-again)
- [The Etiquette Room](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45907/the-etiquette-room)
- [A Cleverly Disguised Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/a-cleverly-disguised-word)
- [A very short story, with letter swaps](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45926/a-very-short-story-garbled)
- [A Puzzle With Weird Genii Making Deli Meat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46141/5373)

As the whirring slows down, you hear a lot of yelling... and notice several spears pointed directly at you.

Welp, this is *bad*.

You're gonna have to find a way to calm these people down, and fast. You desperately try to think of things to show them to convince them that you're worth keeping around, at least out of curiosity. Mathematics? No, they don't have algebraic notation, so you'd have to somehow convey a concept without words. Maybe there's something on your phone? But there aren't any internet connections in ancient Rome (or at least, you *think* that's where you are). While fumbling around in a desperate panic, you notice that the back of the device has come loose, and inside there appears to be some sort of diagram. Maybe this was placed in there intentionally? Could this give you the clue you need?

[image]

Comment: The previous conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49208/discussion-on-question-by-deusovi-community-metapuzzle-the-broken-time-machine).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Metapuzzle Answers

> Gordon K: Silicon
>  Beastly Gerbil: Bigfoot
>  Hugh Myers: Ditto
>  Rand Al'Thor: Simplistic
>  Alconja: Violin
>  GentlePurpleRain: Incognito
>  Julian Rosen: Idiotic
>  'Q': Digit
>  Dcyfj: Windowshopping

I noticed:

> The only vowels are I and O, and an I starts every such string, treat these as binary.

Plugging these into the using [this decoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mKsH.png) blatantly stolen from [ffao](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33774041#33774041)

Results in

> Gate A: BeastlyGerbil + Gordon K = 4 + 6 = 10
>  Gate B: Alconja ^ Hugh Myers = 5 ^ 2 = 25
>  Gate C: Hugh Myers * GentlePurpleRain = 2 * 10 = 20
>  Gate D: Julian Rosen - Rand Al'Thor = 13 - 7 = 6
>  Gate E: Dcyfj / 'Q' = 9 / 3 = 3

And the next step:

> Gate F: D - Ground = 6 - 0 = 6
>  Gate G: B * C = 25 * 20 = 500
>  Gate H: A ^ E = 10 ^ 3 = 1000
>  Gate I: D / D = 6 / 6 = 1
>  Gate J: E + D = 3 + 6 = 9

And now, to get letters

> We're in Rome (maybe), and these look like Roman Numerals so...
> VIVID MIDI MIX

So I pull out my phone

> Open the music app, and play this sick video game music jam that was apparently downloaded onto it by whoever drew this diagram. The centurions are impressed by this wondrous sound, and don't even stab me a little bit.